# Are there cases where vi is the only option?

Tags: vi

Are there scenarios where `vi` is the only option to create, edit or modify a file in an Ubuntu environment?

My question is basically to really know if there is such a case where I would be forced to use `vi` because it would be the only option available in a particular case in the Ubuntu ecosystem.

Could a particular case exist where I somehow would not have access to other options like `nano`, `pico` or simply sending the information with tools like `cat`, `sed`, `tee` and more?

I would assume this is more of a server or cloud side since on the Desktop there are many more options, but from anybody that uses the terminal a lot I ask:

Is there such a case?

Comment: [Use only visudo to edit the sudoers file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/why-do-we-need-to-use-visudo-instead-of-directly-modifying-the-sudoers-file)

Comment: @CAB yep, but I [just realised](http://askubuntu.com/a/516823/186134) that that actually uses nano... :)

Comment: @Tim Actually [`visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/visudo.8.html) can use any editor. Since its default configuration on Ubuntu respects the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables, you can run `sudo env VISUAL=emacs visudo` for emacs or even `gksudo env VISUAL=gedit visudo` for a graphical editor like Gedit. (`sudo -H` or `sudo -i` may be used in place of `gksudo`.) I suggest this [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/env.1.html) way as `VISUAL=emacs sudo visudo` won't work (`sudo` resets most of the environment) and `sudo -EH` *might* be considered inadvisable.

Comment: vi is the only option ... when vi is the only editor installed that you know and you don't want to spend time installing another. vi is the best option when vi is the editor you know/like best among those available and you don't want to spend time installing one you like more. There is NEVER a case where only one tool can solve a problem; there may be times when the choices are constrained. And some people actually like vi. (Not me. I'm an Emacs bigot. Though I can tolerate many editors.)

Comment: `cat`? `sed`? Really? `vi` really is not that complicated, and if you really cannot be bothered to learn it, you only have to remember two modes (Normal and Insert mode). You move the cursor with arrows (or HJKL if not available), press "i" to start editing (insert mode). Once you are done, press "Esc" to go back to normal mode. Type ":wq" to save and quit (Write + Quit).

Comment: Situations where your sys-admin is lazy and only uses `vi`, so other editors aren't installed and he/she refuses. I've been told to suck it up and learn `vi` by system admins from amateurs through HPC experts. (And for that matter, to use `csh` instead of `bash` because they didn't want to write their custom environment scripts again).

Comment: @Eliah yep realised that now :) Turns out nano is my default!

Comment: This isn't as much an answer as a historical observation. N years ago when AIX was new a company I worked for did a project for IBM. Our AIX system had emacs; I'd never even learned vi. Theirs didn't. I couldn't afford to look unix ignorant when I visited in Austin to demo our project - so I learned enough vi for the occasion.

Comment: just suck it up and learn vi :)  Its not as hard as it first appears and once you know it you'll never waste time hunting for other editors on any new system you use.

Comment: @EliahKagan `sudo` accepts environment variables directly before the command that `sudo` is to run, like `sudo VISUAL=emacs visudo`.  There is no need (in this case) to use `env`.

Comment: @JonathanCallen Yes, you're quite right. (`gksu`/`gksudo` does *not* accept this syntax, however.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Inside the **Ubuntu** ecosystem, I do not think this case **can even exist**, as `vi` would at least be a vim-tiny, which is already a “real `vim`” far from “real `vi`.”

In the context of **resource limited** embedded systems,  which are not normally Ubuntu, you may just have a `vi` that turns out to be a link to **`busybox`**. And not space left.  Then, `vi` is the only option.

Apart from that, I think situations where `vi` the only option are **not very common** at all today, even **outside the Linux world**.

But there can easily be situations where `vi` is **the only option you can plan for**,
the only option that certaily will exist in some future situation — which will happen inside a customer’s over-chilled server room, most probably.

Imagine you are called by a customer:

> **Customer:** I need to get this configuration fixed! Now!! I don’t know how, but I can tell you where the configuration file is. Can you help me!?!
>
> **You:** Ok, what kind of system is that running on?
>
> **Customer:** Oh, it's on server foo, ahh... it's running... can't remember, **something with "ix" in the end**, or mayeb with "ux"...

No problem, by now, you know there will be `vi`!

Comment: I have personally worked on a number of embedded systems which contained only vi as a text editor, I believe buildroot and yocto both have it as the only editor when using minimal config options. Admittedly this is not an issue on ubuntu, but if you are an embedded dev this can be a real issue. However you can always as the OP said use pipe based tools such as sed, sort, grep and such, however this can be very painful.

Comment: The *busybox* case is indeed a good one. What's annoying about it is, I don't think it's even a full *vi* (at least it wasn't a decade ago, and I *hope* they haven't bloated it up, even if it is annoying).

Comment: `busybox` `vi` is 4k lines:  `curl -s https://gitorious.org/busybox/busybox/raw/1c7a58dfb82ea04c525e0c19f94f2d800dee99e3:editors/vi.c | wc` ;)

Answer (score 17):

Vi is never the only option; you can always use [`ed`](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) instead.

Comment: In Arch Linux, for example, `ed`'s not part of the `base`.

Comment: @muru FWIW `vim` isn't either.

Comment: @Sparhawk `vi` is.

Comment: @muru Ah yes, of course. I was confusing myself.

Comment: `ed` is only part of the `standard^` install. If you do a `minimal` install, `ed` isn't included.

Comment: Can you not use `ed` commands in `vi`?

Comment: @cpast: I believe t\hat is the joke. `vi` is a improvement over `ed`

Comment: @Oxinabox I know `vi` is a descendant of `ed`; I was replying to @muru and @Oli and that's why I was confused.

Answer (score 13):

Well, there is one case where you need the `vi` editor, lets assume:

- there is not graphical interface
- you're on some strange unknown `*nix` system
- your terminal look like this:

[image]

- you have enough of guys like this:

[image]

As you can see there is **no numerical keypad**. With the old `vi` (and I mean the [original traditional `vi`](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/), not `vim`, `vim.tiny`, or `vim.basic`) you can edit a file with this keyboard. **Without arrow keys**? Yes, when you're in command mode you moved through the file with <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>, like a pro. <kbd>h</kbd> was left, <kbd>j</kbd> was down, <kbd>k</kbd> was up and <kbd>l</kbd> was right.

Comment: I think this answer is actually not that bad (typewriter-like keyboards not a completely unlikely thing to encounter), but in fact that doesn't mean you need `vi` in particular. All older text editors have "backup" key combinations that allow you to work without arrow keys etc., though I daresay that `vi` is the only editor where you wouldn't miss the arrow keys.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: I don't see why you would need a numerical keypad for *any* text editor, and arrow keys are useless in Vim anyway. :P

Comment: Hey, don't discount good old `ed`! No need for these "visual" gimmicks on a system like that! Just try using vim on paper terminal and see how you manage... More seriously, knowing `ed` is useful anyway, it's a decent option when editing needs to be scripted.

Comment: how do you switch to command mode with that keyboard (I don't see escape; was there another key combo for that?)

Comment: @Foon There is an escape key =) It's where tab should normally be. To the left of the  *Q*-key.

Comment: @Doorknobs: Numpads used to be more common than dedicated arrow keys.

Answer (score 6):

Fact of the matter is that, in many distributions editors like `nano` and `pico` just aren't standard while other packages, namely `vim-tiny` are. [See here for the package list of ubuntu-minimal, `vim-tiny` is the only editor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-minimal). [According to this answer, it seems to be the case for Ubuntu server, as well.](https://askubuntu.com/a/271396/284690) I know this is the case for base Debian, Fedora as well.

That being said, given that if you have `nano` on  your system I've yet to see a case where you'd HAVE to use `vi` instead, but, playing off @Volker's answer, if you're working for a customer and don't have root access? `apt-get install nano` isn't going to do you much good (if it even has access to the outside internet!).

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of cases where `vi` (and by that I naturally mean `vim.tiny` because that's what we ship) *could be* the only interactive editor. If we ignore butterflies and cosmic-rays, these seem like the most likely occasions where this could happen:

- You're only using the `ubuntu-minimal` base meta-package. This depends on `vim-tiny`  but no other editors. I can't currently find a way to install Ubuntu without the `standard^` task but you can remove it after installation with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove $(apt-cache show standard^ | awk '/Package: / {print $2}')
  ```

  I have personal experience where I've been handed a system image without the `standard^` task installed. If I hadn't had network access `vi` would have been my only option.
- Chrooting into an environment that only mapped `vi` through
- Manually nuking all the other editors (and disabling the means to reinstall them)
- Manually breaking the shell to stop known editors except `vi` being launched.

A true-minimal install will be the most likely reason but those are fairly rare these days. Some VPS and cloud hosting companies use them (to save disk space as much as anything else) but I would suggest that they are definitely not the norm.

Comment: An awesome answer as always. I find it very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2):

In cases where you are not able to install emacs, or in cases where you need to modify a configuration file in order to enable you to install emacs.  :-p

Comment: Or in cases when you want to use a superior editor that's better than emacs. (*cue flamewar*) :P

Comment: Surely, if you're using Ubuntu then you already *have* an operating system, so emacs would be redundant :v

Comment: Hey, nice comback.   :-p

Answer (score 2):

Many (most?) Busy-Box installations only have `vi`.

It's not ubuntu specific, but it is true of *many* embedded devices.

Answer (score 2):

There's always cat, head, tail ... so I am not sure there is system where you do not have any alternative, but it's possible to find systems where there is not a *better* alternative even if you prefer emacs.

My example was a system I once administered, that was either so slow (or the line was slow and lossy), that when navigating with cursor keys, it often suddenly switched to insert and injected garbage into the edited file, and using HJKL for movement was the only reliable option.

Comment: And of course ꝩe good old [butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/)!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the case where vim is the only option within Ubuntu ecosystem: `Ubuntu Snappy` doesn't come with any text editor other than `vim-tiny`. Perhaps in future there will be one, but not as of 2015-16.  If you are going to be using Ubuntu Snappy over serial console or ssh, you better be prepared to use `vim`.

Answer (score 0):

I got myself into a situation once where only vi's linemode was working. Something having to do with having really screwed up terminal definitions. Basically only vi in linemode (this behaves like normal vi if you pretend you have a 1 line terminal), ex, and ed were going to work because the only terminal definition was "dumb".