# Ubuntu Server minimal package

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, security

What is the best why to install an Ubuntu Server image with the minimum possible of package ( no default, no extrat ) that can only allow ssh connection to it and nothing else.

Comment: Nothing else? Why, then, connect via SSH?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Ubuntu "Minimal CD", aka the "minimal ISO image", is close enough to what you are looking for.

- "Installation/MinimalCD": http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

After doing a minimal install, I think there's only one more thing you need to do to allow ssh connection:

The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/) says (in the [OpenSSH Server section](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html)) that

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

allows people to ssh to your server.
You'll probably also want to to the other things suggested at [How do I configure a new Ubuntu installation to accept ssh connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51925/how-do-i-configure-a-new-ubuntu-installation-to-accept-ssh-connections) .

EDIT:

If on one machine one installs the "Minimal CD", and then runs

```
sudo tasksel install server
```

and on another machine one installs the "Ubuntu Server CD",
my understanding is that the two machines are practically the same.

If you know what the difference is between them, please post that difference to
[Is using Ubuntu Minimal any different from Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44185/is-using-ubuntu-minimal-any-different-from-server)
.

See [What does the "Basic Ubuntu Server" package contain in software selection during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153265/what-does-the-basic-ubuntu-server-package-contain-in-software-selection-during)
for more details.

Comment: But dose the minimal install give the same capability as the server install like lower latency and with different task scheduler ? my goal is to have the most robust and minimal server release to e able after to install some software on top without having any extra or default package that i don't need.

Comment: Replace `linux-generic` by `linux-rt`(this fork is not built in all architectures, e.g.SecureBoot signed)