# Need an Ubuntu Server image with the minimum possible kernel and packages

Tags: 16.04, server, package-management, ubuntu-minimal, configuration-management

I need to build an Ubuntu (16.04 at the moment) base server image for deployment for compliance.  We do not want things like...

- any added libraries (like python, perl)
- apt/aptitude/etc (we'll use Chef or Packer.io or something to build an image)
- vim
- ssh/sshd, sh/bash/etc.
- ping
- iputils
- bzip, gzip, tar,
- more, less
- sudo

  and so forth.

Red Hat has a "minimal" - I see Ubuntu has:   Core, MinimalCD, and NetBoot, however, these seem to require network and go and install the "base" Ubuntu image with this sort of stuff.  For example, I just did the "Mini"CD which is 57MB, and I didn't select "base" or "standard system utilities", however, it still installed all sorts of stuff...  1.2GB total.  150 packages and 120 libraries...

Research:
This one doesn't answer the question, is too old to resurrect, and the answer starts with "Perhaps" : [Ubuntu Server minimal package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652422/ubuntu-server-minimal-package)

Further goals include minimizing disk and memory usage for VM/Cloud cost savings.

Comment: Rather than starting with Ubuntu and chopping off chunks until it doesn't work, why not use Linux From Scratch ( http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ ), and build up to what you want?

Comment: Red Hat has a minimal image which doesn't include rpm and bash? Colour me amazed. Ubuntu without apt/dpkg is no longer Ubuntu, since, at that point, all you have left is the kernel and any software you install from source. Also, most of the software you list don't come installed by default in a server, so I don't see the point of most of this.

Comment: The point is that the Dev/DevOps teams insist on Ubuntu, not Linux from Scratch, not RHEL.

Comment: @MikeP if your devops team insists on an Ubuntu without bash or dpkg, fire them for gross incompetence.

Comment: @muru, your comment is unhelpful, inflammatory, and ad hominem.

Comment: But not inaccurate. If you just want libc and the kernel, what remains is in effect not Ubuntu, since none of the tools associated with Ubuntu are available.