# How to get a mininal ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server, xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu

I want to install 16.04 LTS. But it contains a lot of useless packages for me. I want a minimal version.
Are there any distributions that are cropped? Or how to crop it？

Comment: Related: [Need an Ubuntu Server image with the minimum possible kernel and packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944376/need-an-ubuntu-server-image-with-the-minimum-possible-kernel-and-packages); [How to convert existing Ubuntu install to minimal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987560/how-to-convert-existing-ubuntu-install-to-minimal)

Comment: Do you want Ubuntu Desktop (with a graphical desktop environment) or Ubuntu Server (with a text screen desktop environment) and remote access, for example via a webmin interface or `ssh`? In the first case, yes, there are Ubuntu community flavours with lighter desktop environments: Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie,Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu. The Ubuntu `mini.iso` needs an internet connection during the installation. But maybe it will work for you to install from an Ubuntu Server iso file.

Comment: @sudodus I do not need a graphical desktop environment and remote access, the command line interface is sufficient. Which distribution does this meet this requirement?

Comment: If you can use a wired connection, you can install from an Ubuntu `mini.iso`. Otherwise I would suggest that you install from an Ubuntu Server iso file, and install only the minimal system possible (avoid any 'extra' server packages). I would recommend that you install a version with long time support, 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: You find it at [this link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/) and I suggest the file `ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso` or even better via the corresponding torrent file. You can find the 16.04.1 version via [this link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/), `ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso`

Answer (score 3):

I recently tried "Minimal Ubuntu" for Ubuntu v18.04 LTS on my System. It worked perfectly fine. If you wish to try the same for Ubuntu v16.04 LTS, the steps would remain almost the same.  Refer the below weblinks for more details:

- [Ubuntu Adds Minimal Install Option](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-18-04-minimal-install-option)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Minimal Install Guide](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-18-04-lts-minimal-install-guide/)
- [Minimal Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal)

You can also refer to this web link: [Minimal ISO Images](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Hope these links help you out too.

Comment: 16.04 does not support Minimal Install. Minimal ISO Images need download resources from the web, My server cannot access the network during the installation process. I am confused about Minimal Ubuntu, can it be installed on server?

Comment: Please do not post answers depending on external links. Put the relevant part into your answer (or post the link as a comment to the question if you have enough reputation). See [answer] for details.

Comment: Apologies sir. I have deleted the comment. Will republish the relevant data.